# I can't see the Update program on Lubuntu 15.10

Tags: lubuntu, 15.10

I've recently installed Lubuntu 15.10 on my laptop and I dont see the Update program and I don't know how can I find it.

My PC is Toshiba NB300 with 1gb RAM and Lubuntu 15.10 x32 in the Spanish version.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's normally in the menu under System Tools.  It's called Software Updater.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know but I didnt have it :(

Comment: If you use 'run' in the main menu and type `update-manager` is it found?

Comment: "Failed to execute child process "update-manager" (No such file or directory)"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fix to this problem.

I reinstall Lubuntu but in the installation setup I clicked Download updates when its installing. I restart the pc and now I have the OS 100% in Spanish (Before I have it 50% Spanish-50% English) and the Software Updater program.